# Codeigniter get 2 columns from result row()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can't seem to find the documentation on how to do this correctly... can I not pull 2 columns from a result row?

my user model

```
// log user in
    public function login($email, $password){
        // validate
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        $result = $this->db->get('users');

        if($result->num_rows() == 1){
            return $result->row(0)->user_id;
            return $result->row(2)->gamertag;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Code will never reach your second `return`... instead return `$result->row`

Comment: thing is I was trying not to pull password data if i didnt have to.

Comment: you can use $this->db->select('user_id,gamertag'); before where If you want values from only two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function login($email, $password){
    // validate
    $this->db->select('user_id,gamertag');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $this->db->from('users');
    $result = $this->db->get();

    if($result->num_rows() == 1){
        return $result->row();

    } else {
        return false;
    }
```